# The use of the system in the organization

Tags: system

Good afternoon the question is Elementary OS Loki paid or free to install in your organization system? Can after installing it on the computers in the organization to be problems with the regulatory authorities in Russia?A little weird the way the site at the same time there is written that you need to pay,but if the graph

Answer (score 1):

elementary OS is available for "pay what you want" which includes $0. You can always enter "$0" as the payment amount to download for free. You are also welcome to download once and install on as many computers (i.e. in an organization) as you would like!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply) and if it is certainly will be some kind of problem with the inspection bodies,what document can prove that this free system?) if not difficult can any link to the document?) to print and not to worry))

Comment: You could enter 0$ and then make a screenshot (and print it). Authorities could confirm that it is indeed possible and legal to download for free (that you didn't pirate or steal it). You can't get a receipt for NOT paying. I can't see how you could get in trouble for using a free open source operating system.